# Associate Nested Node in XML to Parent Node while Looping

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

i have  this   segment   of   XML  and  i have   been struggling   to write  either  a C#  or a VB.NET  that will   allow   me  to loop throw  each  ROWDETAIL (Parent node) accessing  innertext value  of  its  nodes  Plus
 BATCH(Child node) accessing  innertext value .

This  is what  i have   so far

```
 Dim nodes_rows As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/PURCHASE_INVOICE/IDOC/ROWDETAIL")
 Dim nodes_batchs As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/PURCHASE_INVOICE/IDOC/ROWDETAIL/BATCH")

 For Each nodes_row As XmlNode In nodes_rows 
     ITEMCODE = nodes_row.SelectSingleNode("ITEMCODE").InnerText
     DSCRIPTION = nodes_row.SelectSingleNode("DSCRIPTION").InnerText

     For Each nodes_batch As XmlNode In nodes_batchs
         BATCHNUM = nodes_batch.SelectSingleNode("BATCHNUM").InnerText
         BATCHQTTY = nodes_batch.SelectSingleNode("BATCHQTTY").InnerText
     Next
 Next



<ROWDETAIL>
  <ITEMCODE>1000000</ITEMCODE>
  <DSCRIPTION>Tablet PC 64GB White</DSCRIPTION>
  <QUANTITY>18</QUANTITY>
  <WHSCODE>01</WHSCODE>
  <UNITPRICE>700</UNITPRICE>
  <VATGROUP>I1</VATGROUP>
  <PRICEAFTERDISCOUNT>600</PRICEAFTERDISCOUNT>
  <BATCHFLAG>YES</BATCHFLAG>
  <BATCH>
    <BATCHNUM>A1SD</BATCHNUM>
    <BATCHQTTY>18</BATCHQTTY>
    <EXPDATE>02.11.17</EXPDATE>
  </BATCH>
</ROWDETAIL>
<ROWDETAIL>
  <ITEMCODE>20000000</ITEMCODE>
  <DSCRIPTION>Tablet PC 64GB White</DSCRIPTION>
  <QUANTITY>18</QUANTITY>
  <WHSCODE>01</WHSCODE>
  <UNITPRICE>700</UNITPRICE>
  <VATGROUP>I1</VATGROUP>
  <PRICEAFTERDISCOUNT>600</PRICEAFTERDISCOUNT>
  <BATCHFLAG>YES</BATCHFLAG>
  <BATCH>
    <BATCHNUM>A1SD</BATCHNUM>
    <BATCHQTTY>12</BATCHQTTY>
    <EXPDATE>02.11.17</EXPDATE>
  </BATCH>
  <BATCH>
    <BATCHNUM>A1SD</BATCHNUM>
    <BATCHQTTY>6</BATCHQTTY>
    <EXPDATE>02.11.17</EXPDATE>
  </BATCH>
</ROWDETAIL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier by using [xsd2Code](https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/), after generating a schema for your XML, the tool will generate classes out of it and even de-/serialization methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove nodes_batchs and use nodes_row to select childs.

```
Dim nodes_rows As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/PURCHASE_INVOICE/IDOC/ROWDETAIL")

For Each nodes_row As XmlNode In nodes_rows 
    ITEMCODE = nodes_row.SelectSingleNode("ITEMCODE").InnerText
    DSCRIPTION = nodes_row.SelectSingleNode("DSCRIPTION").InnerText

    For Each nodes_batch As XmlNode In nodes_row.SelectNodes("BATCH")
        BATCHNUM = nodes_batch.SelectSingleNode("BATCHNUM").InnerText
        BATCHQTTY = nodes_batch.SelectSingleNode("BATCHQTTY").InnerText
    Next
Next
```

If batch appears only once in detail, you dont have to use for each at all. You can replace for each like:

```
        BATCHNUM = nodes_row.SelectSingleNode("BATCH/BATCHNUM").InnerText
        BATCHQTTY = nodes_row.SelectSingleNode("BATCH/BATCHQTTY").InnerText
```

Answer (score 0):

Try XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants("ROWDETAIL").Select(x => new {
                itemCode = x.Element("ITEMCODE").Value, 
                description = x.Element("DSCRIPTION").Value,
                quantity = (int)x.Element("QUANTITY"),
                code = x.Element("WHSCODE").Value,
                price = x.Element("UNITPRICE").Value,
                group = x.Element("VATGROUP").Value,
                discount = x.Element("PRICEAFTERDISCOUNT").Value,
                batchFlag = x.Element("BATCHFLAG").Value,
                batches = x.Elements("BATCH").Select(y => new {
                   number = y.Element("BATCHNUM").Value,
                   quantity = (int)y.Element("BATCHQTTY"),
                   expDate = DateTime.ParseExact(y.Element("EXPDATE").Value, "MM.dd.yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                }).ToList() 
            }).ToList();

        }
    }

}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (System.XML.Linq)

```
    'to load XMLdta from a source see
    'one of the XElement.Load methods

    Dim XMLdta As XElement = <rows>
                                 <ROWDETAIL>
                                     <ITEMCODE>1000000</ITEMCODE>
                                     <DSCRIPTION>Tablet PC 64GB White</DSCRIPTION>
                                     <QUANTITY>18</QUANTITY>
                                     <WHSCODE>01</WHSCODE>
                                     <UNITPRICE>700</UNITPRICE>
                                     <VATGROUP>I1</VATGROUP>
                                     <PRICEAFTERDISCOUNT>600</PRICEAFTERDISCOUNT>
                                     <BATCHFLAG>YES</BATCHFLAG>
                                     <BATCH>
                                         <BATCHNUM>A1SD</BATCHNUM>
                                         <BATCHQTTY>18</BATCHQTTY>
                                         <EXPDATE>02.11.17</EXPDATE>
                                     </BATCH>
                                 </ROWDETAIL>
                                 <ROWDETAIL>
                                     <ITEMCODE>20000000</ITEMCODE>
                                     <DSCRIPTION>Tablet PC 64GB White</DSCRIPTION>
                                     <QUANTITY>18</QUANTITY>
                                     <WHSCODE>01</WHSCODE>
                                     <UNITPRICE>700</UNITPRICE>
                                     <VATGROUP>I1</VATGROUP>
                                     <PRICEAFTERDISCOUNT>600</PRICEAFTERDISCOUNT>
                                     <BATCHFLAG>YES</BATCHFLAG>
                                     <BATCH>
                                         <BATCHNUM>A1SD</BATCHNUM>
                                         <BATCHQTTY>12</BATCHQTTY>
                                         <EXPDATE>02.11.17</EXPDATE>
                                     </BATCH>
                                     <BATCH>
                                         <BATCHNUM>A1SD</BATCHNUM>
                                         <BATCHQTTY>6</BATCHQTTY>
                                         <EXPDATE>02.11.17</EXPDATE>
                                     </BATCH>
                                 </ROWDETAIL>
                             </rows>

    For Each xe As XElement In XMLdta.Elements
        Dim ITEMCODE As String = xe...<ITEMCODE>.Value
        Dim DSCRIPTION As String = xe...<DSCRIPTION>.Value

        For Each bxe As XElement In xe...<BATCH>
            Dim BATCHNUM As String = bxe...<BATCHNUM>.Value
            Dim BATCHQTTY As String = bxe...<BATCHQTTY>.Value
            Dim expDt As String = bxe...<EXPDATE>.Value
        Next
    Next
```